# 入れ子構造のリストにリストを追加したい

Tags: python

`docs=[[A],[B],[C]]` という入れ子構造のリストに[D]というリストを追加し、
`docs2=[[A],[B],[C],[D]]` という入れ子構造のリストを作りたいです。

```
docs2= docs + [d]
```

とすると
`[[A],[B],[C],D]` となってしまいます。

どなたか該当のコードが分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ちなみに単純に質問通りに`docs=[[A],[B],[C]]`としたらエラーになったので、各要素は文字列に変えました。
以下は単純に入力した時のエラー

```
>>> docs=[[A],[B],[C]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
>>>
```

以下のようにコピーして`append`すれば出来るでしょう。
[Pythonで配列や行列の結合](https://qiita.com/Umaremin/items/22de1ca413176e4a19a6)

```
import copy

docs = [['A'],['B'],['C']]

docs2 = copy.deepcopy(docs)
docs2.append(['D'])
```

`copy.deepcopy()`しないと、`docs2`に`docs`を代入して`append`すると`docs`の方も同じく変化します。
[リストの複製、浅いコピーと深いコピー](https://webbibouroku.com/Blog/Article/post-1558)

Answer (score 2):

```
docs2 = docs + [[d]]
```

他の回答にあるように、入れ子構造の場合浅いコピーでいいのか、深いコピーが必要なのかという問題がありますが、`deepcopy` が必要なければこれで十分でしょう。